# Can't call function in c

Tags: c

I am trying to call a function in the following way:
Before int main:

```
int matrixCheck(int matrix[][LEN] , int j , int i);
```

Call in the main:

```
flag =  matrixCheck(matrix[][LEN] , int j , int i);
```

The function itself:

```
int matrixCheck(int array[][LEN] , int j , int i)
```

and I am receiving the following error `error: syntax error before ']' token` (The call in the main)

There is no error before the call because it has only the following code before it.

```
int matrix[][LEN] = {{16,2,3,13},{5,11,10,8},{9,7,6,12},{4,14,15,1}};
int i = 0, j = 0;
int flag = 0;
```

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Comment: The first argument is wrong, then you call it with to few arguments.

Comment: And if that's how you try to call your function, you need to check out [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for a beginners book, and start all over from the beginning again.

Comment: Argument list in your "call in the main" makes no sense syntactically. Get yourself a C tutorial to see how a function call is supposed to look in C.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler says there is syntax error because there is syntax error.

The first argument for calling `matrixCheck` should be `matrix` with no extra `[]` and other junks.

Junk `int` before second and third arguments should also be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The call should be just:

```
flag =  matrixCheck( matrix, j, i ) ;
```

You do not specify data type or array dimensions of arguments in the function call; only in the definition or declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the function does, so I'll make it print the first value of the first group in the array, then it will print the value of j and i.

After function exit, the value of flag will be printed.

I'm not sure if you know how to use a debugger, but if you don't, then at least make use of the printf statement to print out the numeric variables so you can understand how they are processed. See my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 50

int matrixCheck(int array[][LEN] , int j , int i){
    printf("array[0][0]=%d,  i=%d, j=%d\n",array[0][0],i,j);
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int matrix[][LEN] = {{16,2,3,13},{5,11,10,8},{9,7,6,12},{4,14,15,1}};
    int i = 17, j = 18;
    int flag = 0;
    flag =  matrixCheck(matrix,j,i);
    printf("flag=%d\n",flag);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: P.S. I know 50 is an overkill for matrix length, but Its better to allocate just a bit extra than to under-allocate, only to end up with a segmentation fault.

Comment: A debugger will be of no use to him unless he can get the code to compile, and although your code will compile, and may serve as an example, you have not really explained *why* the code in the question does not, which is what the question is about.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know what the function does but you can try with `int array[][]` that is the same like `int **array` -> so a pointer for a two dimensional array.

Comment: as first argument for the function

Comment: That is not an answer to the question, and if mentioned at all should be a comment not an answer.  A valid answer  would be to address the syntax error in the function call. However `int**` has no dimension information `int matrix[][LEN]` is necessary in order to know the span of the first dimension elements.

Comment: Firstly, `int array[][]` is invalid in C. Secondly, a built-in 2D array in C is *not* even remotely the same as "pointer to pointer".